# How can I investigate application/network bottlenecks in my TCP application server and the environment?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, jmeter, firewall

I'm trying to write a high-performance `TCP server` (a `LDAP server`) using [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/) tutorial by `David Fowler` as a base part of the `MyServerListener.cs` to handle incoming connections.

This is a simple `.net 7 console app` (with little changes) that I borrowed from David, it just accepts incoming clients, process the requests and writes `hello` to the response :

```
    internal class Program
    {
        const int PORT = 389; // injecting from config
        const int BACKLOG_LENGTH = 200; // max backlog size in windows server

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listenSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            listenSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            Console.WriteLine("Listening on port " + port);

            listenSocket.Listen(BACKLOG_LENGTH);

            while (true)
            {
                var socket = await listenSocket.AcceptAsync();
                _ = ProcessLinesAsync(socket);
            }
        }

        private static async Task ProcessLinesAsync(Socket socket)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine($"[{socket.RemoteEndPoint}]: connected");
#endif

            // Create a PipeReader over the network stream
            var stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
            var reader = PipeReader.Create(stream);
            var writer = PipeWriter.Create(stream);

            while (true)
            {
                ReadResult result = await reader.ReadAsync();
                ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = result.Buffer;

                while (TryReadLine(ref buffer, out ReadOnlySequence<byte> line))
                {
                    // Process the line.
                    ProcessLine(line);

                    try
                    {
                        // writing a sample message to the response
                        var helloBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello\n");
                        await writer.WriteAsync(helloBytes);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                // Tell the PipeReader how much of the buffer has been consumed.
                reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

                // Stop reading if there's no more data coming.
                if (result.IsCompleted)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Mark the PipeReader as complete.
            await reader.CompleteAsync();

#if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine($"[{socket.RemoteEndPoint}]: disconnected");
#endif
        }

        private static bool TryReadLine(ref ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer, out ReadOnlySequence<byte> line)
        {
            // Look for a EOL in the buffer.
            SequencePosition? position = buffer.PositionOf((byte)'\n');

            if (position == null)
            {
                line = default;
                return false;
            }

            // Skip the line + the \n.
            line = buffer.Slice(0, position.Value);
            buffer = buffer.Slice(buffer.GetPosition(1, position.Value));
            return true;
        }

        private static void ProcessLine(in ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer)
        {
            foreach (var segment in buffer)
            {
                // Doing some tasks
                
#if DEBUG
                Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(segment.Span));
                Console.WriteLine();
#endif
            }
        }
    }
```

This server listens on a port (389), processes the incoming request, doing some jobs and then writes a message to the response using `PipeReader` and `PipeWriter`.
I'm trying to do my best to a less memory/heap allocation code (using `span<>`, `memory<>`, ...) as I can, to keep my codebase so fast and optimize. But for now, I'm trying to test the production environment with the above code to examine the throughput; I mean: the server resources, my TCP server application itself, clients and the network;
I'm using `Apache JMeter` to test (load/stress test).

In some scenarios (sending more than 5000 request/sec) I get `Connection refused` error messages in `JMeter` logs, but I don't have any high pressure in the server or client's (`JMeter[s]`) resources (`CPU/Memory`).

I tried to optimize the server's configuration and changed some `TCP` related parameters (I googled about them) like `MaxUserPort: 65534`, `TcpTimedWaitDelay: 30` or different `backlog` size, but no improvements.
So I'm almost sure that there is sth related to the network (packet dropping/rejecting or sth like this).
I also turned off firewall in the testing clients and the server, But I don't have any access to the network configurations (and I don't know what are they) like firewalls, ISA, TMG, etc.

**_____________**

**Update 1:**
I already increased our clients ephemeral ports to the maximum range using this PS script:

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=5000 num=65535
```

and now we have this :

```
netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp

Start Port : 1024
Number of Ports : 64511
```

And we also checked `JMeter` logs to see any error indicating this situation (Ephemeral ports exhaustion), at first we saw this message :

> Non HTTP response code: java.net.BindException,Non HTTP response
> message: Address already in use

But now, it's gone and we don't have large number of `TIME_WAIT` ports to worry about.
And we are also testing our scenario with `SO_LINGER:0` and monitoring real times `TIME_WAIT` ports (using some tools), and we are sure that this isn't our concern right now.

**_____________**

**So my question is**, how can I find out why I can't send more traffic (threads/requests per seconds in `JMeter` clients) to the server to testing my `TCP` server application performance? Because for now, the server CPU doesn't increase more than ~10%.
At this point, is this a network related problem? How can I be sure about that? e.g: can I use some network analyzers (e.g: `PRTG network monitor`) to find out any dropped `TCP` packets? Or any other tips welcomed

Comment: If your clients are opening a socket per request, you could be experiencing ephemeral port exhaustion.

Comment: @StephenCleary I know what you are saying, and I have handled this situation (I think). I increased my client's ephemeral ports from the default range to the maximum (see my updated question)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably TCP ports are not recycled fast enough, there is a network parameter which controls the time which connection can stay in TIME_WAIT state so you might also want to reduce [TcpTimedWaitDelay](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=system-recycling-tcp-connections-microsoft-windows-operating)

Also it might be a good idea to increase maximum number of TCP connections via [TcpNumConnections](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=itspmwos-increasing-maximum-number-tcp-connections-microsoft-windows-operating-system) parameter

And last but not the least it might be the case JMeter is not capable of sending the requests fast enough so you might need to play the same trick on the load generator side. In addition make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and monitor CPU/RAM/Network/Disk/Swap usage on JMeter side as it might be the case you will need to switch to [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter) if one machine is not capable of giving more than 5k requests per second.

Comment: Yes I read about these parameters (I mentioned them in my question too) and changed them as recommended in this [link](https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Tweaking-Windows-Server-performance-to-prevent-port-exhaustion-when-using-Orion-modules?language=en_US), and we are also using the `JMeter` best practices as u said, we're also using distributed testing with 3 `JMeter` clients, each of them send about 500 req/sec. However, we don't see more than 20% `CPU` load on the server, and we also get some **connection refused** error messages (less than 10%) in `JMeter` logs

Comment: We want to see any logs or proves that show us who is responsible for this : `JMeter` clients or network? Because all we see, is `Connection refused` error messages